# No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have this DTO class:

```
public class UsersXCountry {

    Integer numUsers;
    String countryCode;

}
```

In Repository interface :

```
@Query(value = "select count('1'), country_code from t_user group by country_code",nativeQuery = true)
List<UsersXCountry> usersXCountry();
```

but I getting errors in console:

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.losmundo.backend.domain.UsersXCountry]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
```

Comment: `UsersXCountry` isn't a Spring JPA class ?

Comment: You cannot select individual columns directly into a custom object class with a native query. If you want to do so either use an `interface` instead of a `class`, or use `@NamedNativeQuery` along with `@SqlResultSetMapping` to map the result to a custom object class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names must be identicals beside adding getters, setters to **UsersXCountry**

```
@Query(value = "select count('1') as numUsers, country_code as countryCode from t_user group by country_code",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<UsersXCountry> usersXCountry();
```